Extending line bundle to regular model
Let $S$ be the spectrum of an excellent discrete valuation ring with field of fractions $K$ and $C$ be a proper integral regular curve over $K$. Assume, $C$ admits a proper regular flat model $\mathscr{C} \to S$ and let $\mathcal{L}_{\eta}$ a line bundle on $C$.
Here (arXiv:2110.00545 ) in the proof of Theorem 4.3 (p 41/42) is usued that one can in this setting extend the line bundle $\mathcal{L}_{\eta}$ to a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ over the model $\mathscr{C} $.
This existence should be proved by invoking equivalence of Weil and Cartier divisors on regular schemes: So one can associate with $\mathcal{L}_{\eta}$ a Weil divisor $D \subset C$ and take its closure $\overline{D} \subset \mathcal{C}$ and translate back to Cartierdivs side.
But note there is ambiguity involved: The taking closure operation also  $\overline{D} $ not determine uniquely the scheme structure of the latter, right?
Is it correct that when one refers to such extension without adressing this issue with ambiguity of scheme structure explicitly, one tacitly always takes "by default" closure $\overline{D} $ endowed with reduced scheme structure? (...so I guess that that the extensions of $D$ can be parametrized by scheme structures on $\overline{D}$ embedding the reduced one)
Or is in this specific context the extension of  $\mathcal{L}_{\eta}$ in certain sense"canonical"?

Closure is a scheme theoretic operation: in terms of ideal sheaves, you take the kernel sheaf of the map to the structure sheaf of the divisor in the generic fiber.

@KeerthiMadapusi: ah ok, that was the point for my confusion, I thought that one took there the topological closure & then endowed this with a choosen scheme structure. For scheme theoretic closure the construction is fine! Well, not in full generality, see eg Lemma 29.6.3. here as it could occure troubles with quasi coherence for kernel sheaf in nasty cases, but as in our case the map is quasi compact it's still fine.

An similar, but slightly better approach is to first extend $\mathcal{L}_\eta$ to a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $S$ and then define
$$
\mathcal{L} := \mathcal{F}^{\vee\vee}
$$
to be the reflexive hull of $\mathcal{F}$. The final step is that any reflexive sheaf on a regular surface is locally free.

So in this approach you a priori not impose some additional assumptions on the coh sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ extending $\mathcal{L}\eta$ - only that it is coherent & extends in sense of $\mathcal{L}\eta= j^* \mathcal{F}$ for  $j: C \to S $ ($=\mathcal{C}$ in natation above). This raises naturally the question how close is the approach you described via reflexive hull related to the approach described above via Cartier -Weil corresp. In both approaches there is exactly one choice involved but at different stages. So are these somehow closer related to each other in their mechanism then just these

produce an extension? What is/are the advantage(s) of the approach you presented compared - ie in which sense is it "better" - than to the one I sketched above? Maybe more general - but for both we need to assume regularity

The two approaches are more or less equivalent --- reflexive sheaves of rank 1 play the same role with respect to Weil divisors as invertible sheaves play with respect to Cartier divisors. But you don't need to choose a particular divisor, this allow you to avoid additional choices.

Yes but in approach from your answer we have still to choose a $\mathcal{F}$ extending $\mathcal{L}{\eta}$, and once having this double wedge it.Ok, but is it really "easier" (...or say "better") to choose such "uncut" $\mathcal{F}$ extending $\mathcal{L}{\eta}$, instead just to take closure of assoc Weil div $D$ in $S$ and choose a scheme structure for it? Naively in latter case we can eg endow it with reduced structure -so in certain sense "canonical". On theother hand, is it "easier" or more sophisticated(...in approp sense) to start with a coh $\mathcal{F}$ extding $\mathcal{L}_{\eta}$?

I am afraid this is a question of taste. Some like the more geometric approach of Weil divisors, and some prefer the more algebraic approach of reflexive sheaves.

But what I'm wondering about does there exist in this reflexive sheaf approach a - say "distinguished" - choice for extending $\mathcal{F}$ to start with? (Drawing analogy to the divisor approach one can always pick for closed subspace of a scheme always reduced subscheme structure if one is actually "forced" to make a choice)
